# Unable to lookup fieldnames in R

Tags: r

The dataframe buff contains two columns itemnumber and bufferlevels for different products.

```
   buffer.variant buffer.buf_size
1     mimic1              3

2     mimic2              0

3     mimic3              0

4     mimic4              0

5     mimic5              3
```

Fulfillment is a data.frame with first column as date and variants from buff as other columns. I want to write a loop that:
1.>looks up the column name in the first row of buff
2.>Assigns the first row and ith column cell with the value present in the second column of buff, ie the buffer level

```
variants=names(fulfillment[,-1])
for(i in 1:ncol(fulfillment)){
   fulfillment[1,i+1]=buff[which(buff[,1]==variants[i]),2] }
```

The code fails with the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, i + 1, value = integer(0)):          replacement has length zero
```

Comment: `for(i in 1:(ncol(fulfillment)-1))`

Comment: you can omit the `which`

Comment: use the function ?match

Comment: Used the following code to arrive at the same error:


variants=names(fulfillment[,-1])
     for(i in 1:ncol(fulfillment)-1){
        fulfillment[1,i+1]=buff[match(variants[i],buff[,1]),2]
          }
Error is:  Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, i + 1, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has length zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem. The issue was with R returning a Null. I added a check for null values in the conditional. There was another niggle that @HubertL pointed out, but I only realised when I started printing the value of the iterator i. It was getting initialized to 1 and deprecated to 0 before the program flow went into the 'Then' portion of the code. Here's the code:

```
variants=names(fulfillment[,-1])
for(i in 1:(ncol(fulfillment)-1)){
  if(!is.null(match(variants[i],buff[,1]))){
    print(paste0("step ",i))
    print(paste("old value ",fulfillment[1,i+1]))
fulfillment[1,i+1]=buff[match(variants[i],buff[,1]),2]}
print(paste0("New value ",fulfillment[1,i+1]))
}
```